# Adding Pagination to PHP website, using existing CODE

Tags: php, list, twitter-bootstrap, mysqli

This is my code for displaying a list a videos:

```
<?php

$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
echo "<div class=\"maincover \" data-role=\"scrollbox\" data-scroll=\"vertical\">";

echo "<div class=\"panel panel-default\">";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
echo "<div class=\"panel-heading\">";
echo '<div><a class="panel-title btn-block" href="details.php?id='.$row['id'].'"><h3>'.$row['id'].' | '.$row['vidTitle'].'</h3></a></div>';
echo "</div>";

echo "<div class=\"panel-body\">";
echo "<div class=\"imgCover\"><img class=\"imageCover\"src=\"" . $row['url'] . "\"></div>";
echo "<div class=\"vidSD\">" . $row['vidSD'] . "</div>";
echo "<div class=\"vidDetails\"> 

<hr class=\"style-two\">
<table>
<tr><td class=\"vidDetailsTD\"><strong>" . $lang['vtYear'] . "</strong></td><td class=\"vidDetailsTD\">" . $row['vidYear'] ."</td></tr>
<tr><td class=\"vidDetailsTD\"><strong>" . $lang['vtCity'] . "</strong></td><td class=\"vidDetailsTD\">". $row['vidCity'] ."</td></tr>
<tr><td class=\"vidDetailsTD\"><strong>" . $lang['vtGenre'] . "</strong></td><td class=\"vidDetailsTD\">". $row['vidZanr'] ." , ". $row['vidZanr2'] ." , ". $row['vidZanr3'] . "</td></tr>
<tr><td class=\"vidDetailsTD\"><strong>" . $lang['vtQuality'] . "</strong></td><td class=\"vidDetailsTD\">". $row['vidQuality'] ."</td></tr>
<tr><td class=\"vidDetailsTD\"><strong>" . $lang['vtTranslatedBy'] . "</strong></td><td class=\"vidDetailsTD\">". $row['vidTranslated'] ."</td></tr>
<tr><td class=\"vidDetailsTD\"><strong>" . $lang['vtVideoTime'] . "</strong></td><td class=\"vidDetailsTD\">". $row['vidTime'] .  "</td></tr>
</table> 
</div></div>";

echo " <div class=\"panel-footer\">";
echo '<h6><strong>' . $lang['vsdAuthor'] . '</strong><a href="../userPages/user.php?u='.$row['addName'].'">'.$row['addName'].'</a></h6>';
echo '<div><h6><strong>' . $lang['vsdPublished'] . '</strong>' . $row['published'] . '</h6></div>'; 
echo "</div>";
}
echo "</div></div>";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

I need that at the bottom if I have more than 10 results it will show buttons like this **[CLICK](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#pagination)**
Basically like google use have loads of pages  from 1 to 10, if you open page 10 it will show pages between 5 and 15.

This is another sample of what I want **[CLICK](http://www.developphp.com/view.php?tid=1349)** BUT I'm not sure how to implement this to my code...

Comment: [Twitter Bootstrap Pagination](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#pagination)

Comment: @JayBlanchard I know ... but have no idea how to implement this to my code (((

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, this can not be done only with bootstrap, because it is as frontend framework. 
To do this you must also to a server side pagination, or use JS.

Here is link to tutorial

http://www.techumber.com/2012/08/simple-pagination-with-php-mysql.html

**index.php**

```
include ('paginate.php'); //include of paginat page
$per_page = 5;         // number of results to show per page
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM countries");
$total_results = mysql_num_rows($result);
$total_pages = ceil($total_results / $per_page);//total pages we going to have
//-------------if page is setcheck------------------//
if (isset($_GET['page'])) {
    $show_page = $_GET['page']; //current page
    if ($show_page > 0 && $show_page <= $total_pages) {
        $start = ($show_page - 1) * $per_page;
        $end = $start + $per_page;
    } else {
        // error - show first set of results
        $start = 0;              
        $end = $per_page;
    }
} else {
    // if page isn't set, show first set of results
    $start = 0;
    $end = $per_page;
}
// display pagination
$page = intval($_GET['page']);
$tpages=$total_pages;
if ($page <= 0)
    $page = 1;
```

Comment: I saw a lot of examples and so on, I just can't figure out how to implement in my case, I have like a div(works like iframe) in which displays a list of styles divs(content) , and at the bottom I need 1 to 10 pages, I'm stuck exactly with implementation.

Comment: @Denis did you figure this out?